# Write c program to find mean of two numbers without using division

Tags: c

I just wonder how to find `mean` of two numbers without using division.

do not use these conditions :

- int mean = (a + b) >> 1;
- four fundamental arithmetic operations

Comment: Do you mean the **mean**? **median** is a statistic for a collection of numbers, it's the middle number in the ordered set. E.g. the median of 1, 2, 5, 6, 9 is 5.

Comment: @Barmar you are right, in a collection it is the number in the middle, when you have only 2 numbers you add and divide by two.

Comment: In other words, if there are two middle elements in the collection, the median is the mean of those two.

Comment: @Barmar In computer science, you most definitely _don't_ want to mix up mean and median. For a set of even numbers, you'll just define the index which will be the median, for example given the set 1,2,3,4 you could either say that index 1 (value 2) or index 2 (value 3) is the median.

Comment: @Barmar This becomes important when dealing with digital filters, where medians are used to filter out spikes and mean is used to lower noise. If I have a median-4 filter with values 1,1,500, 999 and then calculate the median as (1+500)/2, then my filter will always fail. If median was based on index 1, it would still be able to filter out the spike.

Comment: @Lundin It really depends on what you're using the median for. If it's statistics, I think they prefer to use the mean of the two middle elements, because it doesn't matter if there's an actual element with that value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this may be helpful -->

```
int a,b,i,j;
if (a>b)
{
    int temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}
for(i=a,j=b;i<j;i++,j--)
    continue;
if(i==j)printf("%d\n", i);
else printf("%lf\n", (double)(i)-0.5);
```

Answer (score 5):

Add them then multiply by 0.5 , no division involved.

Comment: I think the compiler will optimize that. Not sure though, just curious.

Comment: Even better: `int median = (a + b) >> 1;` Oh shoot, someone already set that below.

Answer (score 3):

If they're both integers, you can use a right shift:

```
int median = (a + b) >> 1;
```